# Data from last 12 months each month with trailing 12 months

Tags: t-sql

This is TSQL and I'm trying to calculate repeat purchase rate for last 12 months. This is achieved by looking at sum of customers who have bought more than 1 time last 12 months and the total number of customers last 12 months.
The SQL code below will give me just that; but i would like to dynamically do this for the last 12 months. This is the part where i'm stuck and not should how to best achieve this.
Each month should include data going back 12 months. I.e. June should hold data between June 2018 and June 2018, May should hold data from May 2018 till May 2019.

[Order Date] is a normal datefield (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)

```
DECLARE @startdate1 DATETIME
DECLARE @enddate1 DATETIME

SET @enddate1 = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) -- Starting June 2018
SET @startdate1 = DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-13,0) -- Ending June 2019
;

with dataset as (
select [Phone No_] as who_identifier,
count(distinct([Order No_])) as mycount
from [MyCompany$Sales Invoice Header]
where [Order Date] between @startdate1 and @enddate1
group by [Phone No_]
),

frequentbuyers as (
select who_identifier, sum(mycount) as frequentbuyerscount
from dataset
where mycount > 1
group by who_identifier),

allpurchases as (
select who_identifier, sum(mycount) as allpurchasescount
from dataset
group by who_identifier
)

select sum(frequentbuyerscount) as frequentbuyercount, (select sum(allpurchasescount) from allpurchases) as allpurchasecount
from frequentbuyers
```

I'm hoping to achieve end result looking something like this:
...Dec, Jan, Feb, March, April, May, June each month holding both values for frequentbuyercount and allpurchasescount.

Comment: Why don't you create a temp table with the structure: MonthID, StartDate, EndDate. And populate it with a while loop? Make a join on the `[Order Date] between StartDate and EndDate` condition in your first cte, and use the MonthID for joining frequentbuyers and allpurchases  in the last select.

Comment: @lakta That sounds like a good way to proceed! Could you write up some code to guide the way down this path both for the temporary table and the changes required in the original code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code. I made a little modification for the frequentbuyerscount and allpurchasescount. If you use a sumif like expression you don't need a second cte.

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#tmpMonths') is not null drop table #tmpMonths
create table #tmpMonths ( MonthID datetime, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)

declare @MonthCount int = 12
declare @Month datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

while @MonthCount > 0 begin
    insert into #tmpMonths( MonthID, StartDate, EndDate )
    select @Month, dateadd(month, -12, @Month), @Month
    set @Month = dateadd(month, -1, @Month)
    set @MonthCount = @MonthCount - 1
end


;with dataset as (
    select m.MonthID as MonthID, [Phone No_] as who_identifier,
    count(distinct([Order No_])) as mycount
    from [MyCompany$Sales Invoice Header]
    inner join #tmpMonths m on [Order Date] between m.StartDate and m.EndDate
    group by m.MonthID, [Phone No_]
    ),
buyers as (
    select MonthID, who_identifier
        , sum(iif(mycount > 1, mycount, 0)) as frequentbuyerscount --sum only if count > 1
        , sum(mycount) as allpurchasescount
    from dataset
    group by MonthID, who_identifier
    )
select 
    b.MonthID
    , max(tm.StartDate) StartDate, max(tm.EndDate) EndDate
    , sum(b.frequentbuyerscount) as frequentbuyercount
    , sum(b.allpurchasescount) as allpurchasecount
from buyers b inner join #tmpMonths tm on tm.MonthID = b.MonthID
group by b.MonthID
```

Be aware, that the code was tested only syntax-wise.

After the test data, this is the result:

```
 MonthID   | StartDate  | EndDate    | frequentbuyercount | allpurchasecount
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-08-01 | 2017-08-01 | 2018-08-01 | 340                | 3702
2018-09-01 | 2017-09-01 | 2018-09-01 | 340                | 3702
2018-10-01 | 2017-10-01 | 2018-10-01 | 340                | 3702
2018-11-01 | 2017-11-01 | 2018-11-01 | 340                | 3702
2018-12-01 | 2017-12-01 | 2018-12-01 | 340                | 3703
2019-01-01 | 2018-01-01 | 2019-01-01 | 340                | 3703
2019-02-01 | 2018-02-01 | 2019-02-01 | 2                  | 8
2019-03-01 | 2018-03-01 | 2019-03-01 | 2                  | 3
2019-04-01 | 2018-04-01 | 2019-04-01 | 2                  | 3
2019-05-01 | 2018-05-01 | 2019-05-01 | 2                  | 3
2019-06-01 | 2018-06-01 | 2019-06-01 | 2                  | 3
2019-07-01 | 2018-07-01 | 2019-07-01 | 2                  | 3
```

Comment: Code runs fine, but there's an issue with the reuslts. Expected results for january 2018 - januar 2019: https://imgur.com/a/zKLHAlG . Your query returns wrong data for all periods: https://imgur.com/a/uFDY9bF

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Wasn't aware that enter would trigger comment to be posted, i've edited my reply with screenshot that show the issue :)

Comment: Could you post some test data with the expected result?

Comment: I've dumped some fake data here: https://pastebin.com/eJkMS1PD  expected results for jan 2018 - jan 2019: https://imgur.com/a/zKLHAlG expected results feb 2018 - feb 2019 https://imgur.com/a/dm4qo1Z

Comment: Also i see that your start and end date does not match with the period in the temp table: https://imgur.com/a/nLBh6O7

Comment: Seems the reason for the issue is that when you are joining the temp table all data basically falls into all periods, so in this dataset we end up getting 26416 results instead of a total possible of 3776 records (each who_identifier is in all MonthID).

Comment: sorry the pastebin link with dummy data was missing the order no column, i've updated that here: https://pastebin.com/4N6AEKmU (phone no, date, order no)

Comment: I made an Edit: changed the Start-End date calculation, and included my result. Still don't know how you get 341 for 201901.. As you can see in my result there's 340.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!  Sorry for the miscommucation; the results you were getting are 100% correct :) thanks for great answer!